# Compression is working but decompression is not

Tags: .net, vb.net, gzip, gzipstream

I am writing some code to compress a byte array into a smaller byte array. Then I would like to decompress it:

```
''' <summary>
''' Receives bytes, returns compressed bytes.
''' </summary>
Function Compress(ByRef raw() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress)
            gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length)
        End Using
        Return memory.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Receives compressed bytes, returns bytes.
''' </summary>
Function DeCompress(ByRef compress() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            gzip.Write(compress, 0, compress.Length)
        End Using
        Return memory.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

(I adopted this code from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/compress-vbnet))

My compression code works but my decompression code gives the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Writing to the compression stream is not
>   supported.

I've tried many variations of `gzip.Read` and swapping around variables. (If I knew how to peer into the VB.NET inner source code, like I can with the JDK perhaps I could reverse engineer my way to a solutions, oh well)

How can I retool my `DeCompress` function to work as intended?

EDIT:
I noticed I got down voted becuase I didn't show the `.Read` method use. Well I can't follow through with the `.Read` algo because my VB.NET does not have a `.CopyTo()` function. I don't understand why:

[image]

Comment: When you are going to decompress, you don't write to the stream, you read from it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GZipStream and decompression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581694/gzipstream-and-decompression)

Comment: I wrote that I tried `gzip.Read` I didn't want to make my question 10 pages long with all my variations of tries.. Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're decompressing, you're trying to write to the decompression stream. That's now how it works - when decompressing, it reads from the stream as you read the decompression stream.

Quick workaround demonstrated below:

```
''' <summary>
''' Receives bytes, returns compressed bytes.
''' </summary>
Function Compress(ByRef raw() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress)
            gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length)
        End Using
        Return memory.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Receives compressed bytes, returns bytes.
''' </summary>
Function DeCompress(ByRef compress() As Byte) As Byte()
    Using output As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(compress)
            Using gzip As GZipStream = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                CopyStreamToStream(gzip,output)
            End Using
            Return output.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


Public Shared Sub CopyStreamToStream(input As Stream, output As Stream)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(16 * 1024 - 1) {}
    ' Fairly arbitrary size
    Dim bytesRead As Integer

    While (InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    End While
End Sub
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
```

Note that I now have "memory" reading from the "compress" byte array, and copying it to a new output stream.

Edit: Added a replacement for `Stream.CopyTo()`, as the questioner must work against .net 3.5

Comment: I've seen code like this, and it didn't work. Namely, the `gzip.CopyTo()` function doesn't exist for me. I believe I am writing code compatible to .NET 3.5 so I don't understand why Visual Studio is yelling at me about `.CopyTo()`

Comment: @E.S. `.CopyTo()` came in .net 4.0, if I'm not mistaken. I'll edit with a .net 3.5 compatible answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the work around for `.CopyTo`!

Answer (score 0):

Example taken directly from the MSDN on [the GZipStream Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Private Sub Decompress(ByVal fileToDecompress As FileInfo)
    Using originalFileStream As FileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead()
        Dim currentFileName As String = fileToDecompress.FullName
        Dim newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length)

        Using decompressedFileStream As FileStream = File.Create(newFileName)
            Using decompressionStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream)
                Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Look how the example reads from the decompresser stream while you attempt to write to it