# How can I access the contents of a .jar file

Tags: c#, minecraft

I am currently developing a minecraft mod Manager in c#. I have access to folder with sub-folders corresponding to the different versions I have installed. Inside these folders are the mods in .jar files.

To this point, I have set up custom naming conventions on the files in order to display the mod name. I have discovered, however, that in each .jar file there is a file with the name mcmod.info containing the name and description of the mod. How can I access that file in the .jar? Best case scenario would be not to extract the .jar first and read the file's contents directly from the .jar. Here is an example of what a mcmod.info looks like:

```
[
{
  "modid": "harvestcraft",
  "name": "Pam's HarvestCraft",
  "description": "Expanding minecraft's food system.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "mcversion": "1.12",
  "url": "http://minecraft.curseforge.com/members/MatrexsVigil/projects",
  "updateUrl": "",
  "authorList": ["Pamela Collins"],
  "credits": "",
  "logoFile": "",
  "screenshots": [],
  "dependencies": []
}
]
```

A detailed answer would very much be appreciated!

Comment: Internally, a `.jar` file is just a `.zip` archive. Therefore, you can access its contents as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762855/1911064).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581694/gzipstream-and-decompression